# SAS: Selecting string list in macro

Tags: macros, sas

I want to loop over different lists, and select different sets of variables, based on one "initial" string.

Example: I have the following lists and sets of variables.

```
%let KRW_list = USD JPY HKD;
%let KRW_vars = FX import export;
%let NZD_list = USD AUD JPY GBP;
%let NZD_vars = FX CA;
```

Now, if I have

```
%let ccy = KRW;
```

then I want to loop over the elements in KRW_list and use the variables in the KRW_vars list. Of course, I could make a macro that took all 3 as arguments. But I want a macro that just use ccy as argument and then selects the correct string lists. I very naively thought of the following:

```
%macro selectlist(ccy1);
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&ccy1._list));
%do I = 1 %to &n;

proc timeseries data = &ccy1._&ccy2. out= tmp;
.....[some commands] ;
var &ccy1._vars ;
run;
%end;
%mend;
```

This doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of the rules surrounding resolution of macro variables. If you set up a macro variable that in turn should resolve to another, SAS needs to know that it has to resolve twice over:

```
%let x_list=a b c;
%let y=x;

%put &y._list;
```

Returns `x_list`, because SAS simply resolves `y` to `x` and then doesn't resolve any further. However:

```
%put &&y._list;
```

First resolves &y to x:

```
&x_list
```

Which then resolves to:

```
a b c
```

If you change `&ccy1.` to `&&ccy1.` in your code, it should then work as you intend it to.

If you turn on `OPTIONS SYMBOLGEN;` (simply include this statement in your code), this will show the macro resolution steps in the log which should help you work out what SAS is doing in the background.

(Run `OPTIONS NOSYMBOLGEN;` to turn off)

Comment: Thanks! However, needed one more &. See below:
%let ccy = KRW;
%let KRW_list = trade bid ask;

proc timeseries data=test out= test2;
id datetime interval=min5 accumulate=last setmissing=previous align=beg;
var &&&ccy._list;
run;

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't have a SAS application to test this in. Happy you found the right answer in the end!